# Tag link does not provide complete list of questions with that tag

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags

I was looking for [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17042/why-didnt-yehoshua-give-a-good-report-immediately), which I speculated was tagged [parshat-shelach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-shelach).  I clicked that tag from another question and didn't find my question.  So I searched for my question, confirmed the tag, and then clicked on that tag from *that* question -- and got a results page with four questions, not including the question I just came from.

The four questions that the tag link does find are: [Calling Hoshea 'Yehoshua' before his seeming renaming](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/calling-hoshea-yehoshua), [What would have happened if the sin of the spies never occurred?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27740/what-would-have-happened-if-the-sin-of-the-spies-never-occurred), [Is there any evidence of Nephilim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28645/is-there-any-evidence-of-nephilim), [Rashi in Shelach 8 days c'neged 8 strings of tzitzis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21976/rashi-in-shelach-8-days-cneged-8-strings-of-tzitzis).  I've been unable to determine what those four have in common that my target question, [Why didn't Yehoshua give a good report immediately?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17042/why-didnt-yehoshua-give-a-good-report-immediately), doesn't have.

Anecdotally I've looked at some tags in the past week or so and thought "hmm, I thought there'd be more questions about that".  I don't think it's just about this tag.

Comment: Are you looking at unanswered questions maybe? Try clicking the active or newest tabs.

Comment: @DoubleAA huh.  Apparently.  I never noticed those filtering links at the top of the tags list, and don't remember recently clicking one to chagne my view.  (Also, that's sticky across all tags views?  Interesting.)  So I don't know how I got into that state, but your diagnosis is correct.